# Possible bug: Integrate forgets sum in integrand if condition is present in integrand

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am encountering problems in Mathematica that can be illustrated by this minimal example:

```
f[x_] := Sum[If[n + x > 0, 2^n, 0], {n, 1, 2}]

f[3]
Out: 6

Integrate[f[x],{x,0,1}]
Out: 2^(n+1)

NIntegrate[f[x],{x,0,1}]
Out:"The integrand If[1+x>0,2^n,0]+If[2+x>0,2^n,0] has evaluated to 
non numerical values for all sampling points in the region with 
boundaries {{0,1}}."
```

For some reason, the sum is performed when doing the integrals, but the dummy variable in the sum is not replaced by the numerical value. Is this a bug? Is there a simple solution to circumvent this for general integrands?

I run Mathematica 11.0.0.0 on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: try also `ClearAll[f]; f[x_] := Sum[With[{n = n}, If[n + x > 0, 2^n, 0]], {n, 1, 2}]`, or `ClearAll[f]; f[x_] := Sum[If[# + x > 0, 2^#, 0] &@n, {n, 1, 2}]` to make sure the value of `n` is injected into the second argument of `If` to circumvent the `HoldRest` attribute of `If`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use `Boole` or `Piecewise` instead of `If` when constructing a numerical function

```
f[x_] := Sum[Boole[n + x > 0] 2^n, {n, 1, 2}]

NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
(* 6 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at

```
Sum[If[n + x > 0, 2^n, 0], {n, 1, 2}]
(*If[1 + x > 0, 2^n, 0] + If[2 + x > 0, 2^n, 0]*)
```

you see that n isn't substituted completely inside `If[]` !

Workaround:

```
Sum[Apply[If, {n + x > 0, 2^n, 0}], {n, 1, 2}]
NIntegrate[%, {x, 0, 1}]
(*6*)
```

Comment: I think the "intended" way to achieve OP's task is to use [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html), like this: `f[x_] := Sum[Boole[n + x > 0] 2^n, {n, 1, 2}]`

Comment: I see, the 'If' is not evaluated in the sum yet because the condition cannot be evaluated (it doesn't know the value of x yet), and then returns the rest including n.

Comment: The point is, the evaluation of sum is done only for the first argument element of `If` . The workaround `Apply` evaluates the complete list of arguments inside `If`